# b.a.readFileSync is not a function React JS

Tags: reactjs, mollie

I'm trying to use the official mollie api. When I run the code local in React JS I get the following error:
[image]
Then I uploaded the code to firebase hosting. There I get the following error:
[image]

The environment can be seen via this link: https://picoo-hire-b2c.web.app/
If you then click on 'test transactie' at the bottom of the page, the error will appear in the console.log.

My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import createMollieClient from '@mollie/api-client';



class formHandeling extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'Picoo',
            email: '',
            firstname: '',
            lastname: '',
            address: '',
            postal: '',
            city: '',
            recommended: '',
            errorMessage: '',
            agreement: false,
            contact: false,
            newsletter: false
        };
    }

    onChangeCaptacha(value) {
        console.log("Captcha value:", value);
      }

    testPayment(){
        createMollieClient({ apiKey: 'test_7K9sDETkbB7ctsJ2TqwyUnkAMf56ur' }).payments.create({
            amount: {
              value:    '10.00',
              currency: 'EUR'
            },
            description: 'Test of picoo mollie',

  redirectUrl: 'https://yourwebshop.example.org/order/123456',
  webhookUrl:  'https://yourwebshop.example.org/webhook'
          })
            .then(payment => {
              // Forward the customer to the payment.getCheckoutUrl()
              console.log("payment:"+payment);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Handle the error
            });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container form-labels">
                <label>
                    Email:<br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.email, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Voornaam:<br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={event => this.setState({ firstname: event.target.firstname, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Achternaam:<br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={event => this.setState({ lastname: event.target.lastname, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Adres:<br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.address} onChange={event => this.setState({ address: event.target.address, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Postcode:<br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.postal} onChange={event => this.setState({ postal: event.target.postal, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Plaats: <br />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.city} onChange={event => this.setState({ city: event.target.city, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Ja, ik ga akkoord met de huurvoorwaarden*
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.agreement} onChange={event => this.setState({ agreement: event.target.checked, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <p>
                    Picoo is toegewijd aan het beschermen en respecteren van je privacy, en we zullen je persoonlijke informatie alleen gebruiken om de producten en diensten te leveren waar je ons om hebt gevraagd.
                </p>
                <label>
                    Ja, ik ben akkoord dat Picoo contact met mij opneemt.*
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.contact} onChange={event => this.setState({ contact: event.target.checked, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Schrijf mij ook in voor de Picoo nieuwsbrief (niet verplicht)
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.newsletter} onChange={event => this.setState({ newsletter: event.target.checked, errorMessage: '' })} />
                </label>
                <p>
                Bekijk ons privacybeleid voor meer informatie.
                <br/><br/>
                Door hieronder op verzenden te klikken, geef je toestemming aan picoo om de hierboven ingediende persoonlijke informatie op te slaan en te verwerken om je van de gevraagde inhoud te voorzien.
                </p>
                <button onClick={() => this.testPayment()}>Test transactie</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default formHandeling;
```

Does anyone have an idea where to start looking?

Comment: That's part of the node fs module. React is front-end so it would be unsafe for it to be able to do things like that.

Comment: But this codes comes from the official documentation, is there an possibility to not use this?

Comment: The official react documentation? That doesn't sound right to me but I would make sure you're using the latest version and then post an issue on their github tracker.

Comment: No sorry the official mollie api documentation

Comment: I don't know what that is, sorry. Maybe @mollie? I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

`@mollie/api-client` is a node module. NodeJS is server-side javascript and you are using this module in React which is the frontend. It may be confusing because both environments use npm to install packages.

You get that error because `fs` is a node lib.

This error should hint to you that you're not using the library in the way it's meant to be used. One very important rule is that probably in 99% of the cases you want your frontend to only make calls to your own backend to avoid security issues.

This means that your frontend calls your backend endpoint with payment info, and then your backend calls mollie to register the payment using `@mollie/api-client`.

The frontend is not secured at all, whatever you put there it's visible to the users. This means that if you do it the way you show in your question, you expose your mollie API key to all your users and you're gonna have a bad time.

Also remember to keep the connection secured between your frontend and backend (use https, in your backend validate any data you get from the frontend, etc.)